# How to set the Image to appear behind the current canvas?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-canvas

I am using canvas to draw the Different colour.
I want to set the Image that should be appear as the background of the canvas. And while i am drawing on that image it should be drawn on the Image not behind the image.
Right now with below code it is drawing behind the Image.

```
 @Override
    public void run() {
        Canvas canvas = null;
        while (_run){
            try{
                canvas = mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);

                canvas.drawColor(0, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);

                commandManager.executeAll(canvas);
            } finally {
                Bitmap kangoo = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.icon);
                canvas.drawBitmap(kangoo, 130, 100, null);

                mSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }
        }

    }
```

So what should i have to do to make drawing on the image ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No one have giving me answer. 
But i got solution, I have to set the image after clearing canvas.

code:

```
 @Override
    public void run() {
        //Canvas canvas = null;
        while (_run){


            try{
                canvas = mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);

                canvas.drawColor(0, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);

                Bitmap kangoo = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.icon);
                canvas.drawBitmap(kangoo, 130, 100, null);
                commandManager.executeAll(canvas);

            } finally {

                mSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

As you redrawing the canvas in While(1) loop you can put the statement `canvas.drawBitmap(kangoo, 130, 100, null)` at the top inside the loop so that its drawn again and again then do you painting over top of it.

If you want to save the drawn part to you do something like converting the Canvas to bitmap like:

```
Bitmap  bitmapToBeDrawnFromNextTime = Bitmap.createBitmap( canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas imageCanvas = new Canvas(bitmapToBeDrawnFromNextTime);
imageCanvas.draw(canvas);
```